# WebSocket over Yamux over WebSocket not working

Tags: go, websocket

I was experimenting [hashicorp/yamux](https://github.com/hashicorp/yamux) over [gorilla/websocket](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket), and got stuck.

I started with vanilla WebSocket using the [echo example](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/tree/master/examples/echo) from Gorilla WebSocket project. It was very a straight forward client-server setup. Then image that the *server* is now behind a firewall, thus the *client* cannot make a direct connection to it. So I introduced a *hub* and an *agent*. The *hub* is supposed to be publicly visible and connectable for the *client*. The *agent* would run alongside the *server*, who would first make a WebSocket connection to the *hub* and then multiplex the connection using Yamux so that the *hub* can then initiate requests to the *server*. In this way, I effectively "exposed" the *server* beyond the firewall.

For normal HTTP endpoints, things are good. The *client* can make requests to the *hub*, who would proxy these requests to the *agent* using the WebSocket connection initiated by the *hub*, and then the *hub* would further proxy these requests to the *server*.

However, this trick failed to work with WebSocket endpoints. For the echo example, the *client* can access the HTML on `/` through the *hub-agent-server* chain, but would fail on the `/echo` path, which is a WebSocket endpoint.

My question is, is this WebSocker over Yamux over WebSocket fundamentally impossible, or do I just need some extra lines to get things work? [Here's the code](https://gist.github.com/fengye87/76791723511f6867b02723ba0c437315) I've been experimenting with. Really appreciate your helps!

Comment: @CeriseLimón I failed to see how to use session Open as the websocket network dialer. I was proxying all requests through the *hub* to the *agent* over yamux. So in fact, the *hub* doesn't know if the endpoint is a websocket or not. Could you be more specific? Thanks!

Comment: @CeriseLimón I could just use a normal TCP socket and Yamux it. Choosing a WebSocket over TCP socket is because I want to "disguise" the whole traffic as HTTP to make some firewall OK with it. But that's just my understanding, correct me if I'm wrong here. Sorry but I still don't get your solution here. Could you paste some code as answer here? I would be happy to test it out and accept it if it works. Thanks!